# Using Sorcery to login with twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorcery

i keep on getting this error

`OAuth::Unauthorized in OauthsController#callback`

401 Unauthorized

In oauth_controller error in this line ---  `@user  = login_from(provider)`

I am using sorcery 0.7.7

my framwork trace

```
oauth (0.4.6) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:216:in `token_request'
oauth (0.4.6) lib/oauth/tokens/request_token.rb:18:in `get_access_token'
sorcery (0.7.7) lib/sorcery/controller/submodules/external/protocols/oauth1.rb:22:in `get_access_token'
sorcery (0.7.7) lib/sorcery/controller/submodules/external/providers/twitter.rb:81:in `process_callback'
sorcery (0.7.7) lib/sorcery/controller/submodules/external.rb:46:in `login_from'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:443:in `_run__203834006__process_action__491933260__callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
```

Comment: I see Sorcery 0.7.12 is available. Have you tried that version? Anything preventing you from upgrading?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Check your twitter app settings:

1. Callback URL should be same, like at your sorcery config file.
2. Access level should be: Read, write, and direct messages
3. Check if in your sorcery config file you have Consumer key and secret, and not Access token and Access token secret.

Comment: `the callback url in sorcery config must same as dev.twitter setting`, thanks for solve my problem.